# New line between 2 spans if text overflows

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML snipper in my application that looks like this:

```html
<div>
  <span class="name">Some Verylongname</span>
  <span class="company">Company</span>
</div>
```

(the html that the browser renders is minified so it actually looks like this: `<div><span></span><span></span></div>`).

I want the text to span 2 lines only if the container element is too small to include everything in the same line. If it has to break I'd like to have it break before the company name if possible (i.e the company name will be in the bottom line and the entire name in the upper line).

Right now, since there is not separation between the `span`s it looks like the browser interprets and last name and the company name as one string and breaks into a line before the last name:

```
Some
VerylongnameCompany
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Is there some other css or something inherited in this instance? Because what you describe is how it should result by default as opposed to what you're seeing. Is there like a 'break-word' property being set on the spans or something?

Comment: This demo - and much of it is purely to see the individual elements - seems to do what you describe, effectively by adding a single white-space character via the generated content: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rawx42v8/ is that what you're looking for, or is there something more complex you need to achieve?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I found the hack with space after the name but it adds white space to the content that should not be there (it interferes with what our designers are aiming for) I was hoping there might be another way.

Comment: @ChrisW. There no other CSS there.

Comment: @DorMesica: could you update the question to include details on what you've tried, and what you consider 'hacks' or unacceptable? It's also worth noting that a simple use of CSS flex-box layout - again - seems to solve the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/rawx42v8/1/

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica I used flex but I forgot about flex-wrap. I really solved it.. Thanks!